# IE7: whitespace nowrap doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have an unordered list. The list items are `inline-block`. I can't and won't use `float:left` because I need to align them to the bottom vertically. Everything's fine. The whole layout works across every browser except IE7 which seems to apply the `whitespace:nowrap;` property on the `ul` in **IE Inspector** but doesn't really apply it. The list items still get stacked when browser's width is small.

```
div#container {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
div#container > ul {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div#container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Can't post a fiddle. Because jsFiddle itself doesn't work on IE7.

Comment: <nobr> doesn't help?

Answer (score 2):

IE7 must be running in a standards compliant mode in order for CSS combinators to work properly.

You can run `alert(document.compatMode);` to see which mode you are running in. If you receive `BackCompat` then you are running in Quirks Mode and CSS combinators will not work. If you receive `CSS1Compat`, then IE7 is running in a standards mode and CSS combinators will work.

The easiest solution is to simply remove the combinators from your CSS:

```
div#container {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
div#container ul {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div#container ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

If you cannot remove the combinators, then you will need to [use a doctype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242(v=vs.85).aspx) to make IE7 adopt a standards compliant mode. In my tests, adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of the document worked fine in IE7.

Comment: I have `<!DOCTYPE html` in my page. Plus, `document.compatMode` gives `CSS1Compat`. It doesn't seem to work though :(

Comment: @RexOverflow Have you tried removing the CSS combinators anyway? When I removed them it worked perfectly for me (i.e., looked the same in IE7 as Chrome). Setting a DOCTYPE also made it work well for me.